# No hot water on high pressure shower head

Tags: plumbing, shower, water-pressure

I just moved into a new apartment.
I noticed that the pressure in the shower is not optimal, but the hot & cold water work fine.
After changing to a higher pressure shower head, the pressure is much better, but now I have no hot water (unless I turn the faucet to the hottest setting, then there's some hot water).

I'm quite sure that it's somehow caused by the new shower head, because when switching back to the original I'm back to where I started.
I can easily try a different shower head, but without knowing the root cause, I don't know what to look for.

Is this a common issue?
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have your own water heater? If so, what's it set at?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the wall on your shower is likely what's called a balancing mix valve, meaning where the hot and cold water pipes converge there is a special valve intended to prevent scalding by controlling how much cold or hot water is let through. There are different types of mixing valves, yours may be sensitive to the pressure in that by changing the pressure at the head, you have upset the balance settings in your mix valve. It might also be that it has the hot side wide open, but the cold is over powering it because of the lower restriction from the new head. You may not be able to fix this, because it might be that the hot supply pipes are corroded and not enough hot water can get though them.

Comment: Thank you @JRaef for your response.
However, I'm not sure that it's related to the mixer in the shower. I actually think it's an issue on the whole apartment. I recently cleaned the filter on a faucet in the sink, afterwards the flow increased but now I have the same issue as with the shower head. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Either overall in the apartment, or at the very least in the shower. Is there a type of shower head designed for this issue? I can't be the only one with the same problem. Thank you for your help